# Дублируются данные в цикле

Tags: javascript, массивы

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой и вообще не понимаю как решить. Есть функция, которая на вход принимает массив из чисел (но он может быть и пустым), и создает несколько наборов чисел (равное tcount)

```html
function createTickets(mas) {
    let ticket = ''
    let tcount = document.getElementById('tcount').value
    for (t = 0; t < tcount; t++) {
        let numbers = []
        numbers.splice(0, numbers.length);
        numbers.length = 0;
        console.log(numbers)
        numbers = generate(mas);
        let ticketItem = ''
        numbers.forEach(n => {
            ticketItem += `<div class="ticket-item" data-select="${n}">${n}</div>`
        })
        ticket += `<div class="ticket-block">${ticketItem}</div>`
        numbers = []
        console.log(numbers)
    }

    ticketslist.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ticket)
    numbers = []
    createTicketsButton.disabled = true
    ticket = ''
}
```

и функция generate(),

```html
function generate(mas) {
    let arr = []
    arr.splice(0, arr.length);
    arr.length = 0;
    let max_number, i, unic;
    arr = (mas.length != 0) ? mas : []
    max_number = 6;
    while (arr.length < 6) {
        do {
            unic = true;
            a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 36) + 1;
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (a == arr[i]) {
                    // такое число уже было
                    unic = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (!unic) // повторить генерацию числа
        arr.push(a);
    }
    return arr
}
```

которая генерирует массив случайных чисел с учетом входящего параметра(массив mas). Проблема в том, что если массив mas пустой, все работает как надо, а если в нем есть элементы - дублирует набор чисел в количестве равном tcount
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Покажите код функции generate

Comment: function generate(mas) {
    let arr = []
    arr.splice(0, arr.length);
    arr.length = 0;
    let max_number, i, unic;
    arr = (mas.length != 0) ? mas : []
    max_number = 6;
    while (arr.length < 6) {
        do {
            unic = true;
            a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 36) + 1;
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (a == arr[i]) {
                    unic = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (!unic) // повторить генерацию числа
        arr.push(a);
    }
    return arr
}

Comment: Прошу прощения, не разобрался как вставлять код в комментарии

Comment: Просто нажмите "править" под вопросом, и дополните вопрос кодом

Comment: спасибо! вставил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас много лишних действий в функциях
Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, вот этот код должен сработать:

```
function createTickets(mas) {
  let ticket = ''
  let tCount = 10

  for (let i = 0; i < tCount; i++) {
    const numbers = generate(mas)

    let ticketItem = ''

    numbers.forEach(n => {
      ticketItem += `<div class="ticket-item" data-select="${n}">${n}</div>`
    })

    ticket += `<div class="ticket-block">${ticketItem}</div>`
  }
}

function generate(mas) {
  const result = mas && [...mas] || []

  while (result.length < 6) {
    const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 36) + 1
    !result.includes(a) && result.push(a);
  }

  return result
}
```

P.S. - не забудьте поменять инициализацию у `tCount` и добавить функции вставки на страницу

Comment: Все то же самое, только теперь он и при пустом массиве дублирует)) Но за вариант с сокращением кода спасибо, только вопрос - !result.includes(a) && result.push(a); includes это же в ES7 только пошло, вроде? Насколько поддерживается этот метод сейчас?

Comment: Во всех современных браузерах. Посмотреть можно здесь https://caniuse.com/array-includes

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы во всех массивах были уникальные значения, а не только в одном? Как будто бы если бы это был один массив уникальных значений, разделённый на несколько массивов?

Comment: Да, в каждой итерации цикла (переменная tCount) должны быть уникальные числа от 1 до 36, в случае если массив mas не пустой, функция generate возвращает 6 чисел, в который входят числа из массива mas, если пустой то генерит произвольные 6 чисел, в одном ticket числа повторятся не должны, но в разных могут повторятся. По сути, это лотерея 6 из 36, функции создают билеты, по которым потом будет тираж, с возможность в каждый билет добавить 3 своих числа

Comment: Я обновил код, попробуйте сейчас

Comment: Супер, спасибо!